# Bad sectors, maybe a dupe?

Tags: hard-drive, 16.10, badblocks

I'm on ubuntu 16.10. 
As of today, I opened the disks tool and noticed my HDD has 1225 bad sectors, no worries.

Five minutes later the count went to 1570. 
Three minutes later it went to 1767.

I've just checked again (five minutes later) and the number went down to 1482.

Is there any possibility that the bad sectors reported are not bad, and it may be a bug?

The disk has always had those original 1225 bad sectors since my laptop ran windows. (mind you, it is a Sony Vaio VPCEG44fx, so it is at least a 6 year old computer.)

I am planning on getting a new one, or a new HDD, and I regularly back up my information, so no worries.

Should I just image the disk instead of backing it up? (just to be sure)

Should I be worried?  (it went to 1496 since I began to write this.)

Is it a bug? (Why it goes up, then down. If the disk was failing shouldn't it just the number keep growing?)

Thanks for any answer given.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it's a 99.99% likelihood that your hard drive is not long for this world.  From your post it sounds like the HDD has had a lot of bad sectors for a very long time.  At 6 years of age it is statistically well past end of life. Naturally there is a big difference between chronological age and powered up age. Time to backup everything you want to save and replace it.

A HDD should have ZERO bad sectors.  I will immediately make plans to replace any drive that has even a single bad sector.  This is simply a good best practice.

I'd recommend installing:

GSmartControl

Click on the drive you want to test and run:

Perform Tests

The above test is non-destructive.  You can also click on a drive and look at:

Device->View Details

The displayed tabs offer a LOT of information on the condition of any smart-enabled drive.

As a general practice, you should run these tests on any new drive before putting it into service and you should look at the smart info periodically to see if the drive is starting to exhibit problems.

I would be cautious about imaging a drive with so many bad sectors.  The chances that there may be corrupt data are significant.

I don't have a lot of experience with the Ubuntu distro but I'm rather surprised that with so many bad sectors the boot process doesn't force an fsck to be run.